# SQL help, selecting specific columns

Tags: sql

I have a nvarchar column which also has non-English (a-z) characters like Crystal77, Bólido Comidas.

How can I specifically select the rows which contain non-English characters in that column?

Thanks

Comment: you mean just the ROWS with non-english characters in the column?

Comment: yes. Rows which contain any non alphabet character

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All rows where any character not in the range a-z

I've used COLLATE with a binary collation to remove the false match against ó... it appears LIKE is ignoring accents but that could be because it's unicode

```
DECLARE @myTable TABLE (myColumn nvarchar(100))
INSERT @myTable (myColumn) VALUES ('Crystal77'), ('Bólido Comidas'), ('PlainEnglish')

SELECT * FROM @myTable
     WHERE myColumn COLLATE Latin1_General_BIN NOT LIKE '%[^ a-zA-Z]%'
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I did 'nt know about ^